# C++ Multithreading - Writing to different keys in same map causing problems

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following function running several times on 6 different threads, with the same nodeMap being passed to each function. I'm sure that the keys being read and written to on each thread are independent (no two threads will have the same histories). Despite this, occasionally this code will output "Preposterous". When working with one thread, this would be impossible, as if `nodeMap` didn't contain `histories[state.currentPlayer]`, then a node with that key would be added to the map, and it would be found in the last if statement.

```
double cfr(std::unordered_map<InfosetHistory, Node>& nodeMap, State& state, const InfosetHistory* histories,
           unsigned char player, std::ranlux24_base& randEngine) {
    ...

    // Find node or create it if it doesn't exist
    if (nodeMap.find(histories[state.currentPlayer]) == nodeMap.end()) {
        if (state.phase == State::DRAW) {
            nodeMap.insert(std::make_pair(histories[state.currentPlayer], Node(state.drawOnlyFromDiscard())));
        } else {
            nodeMap.insert(std::make_pair(histories[state.currentPlayer], Node(state.getAllowedDiscardOptions())));
        }
    }
    if(nodeMap.find(histories[state.currentPlayer]) == nodeMap.end())
        std::cout << "Preposterous" << std::endl;
    ...
```

I'm new to multithreading, so I'm assuming that somehow accessing the same map object from multiple threads is causing problems. I read that as long as the keys are independent, multithreading shouldn't create issues, so I'm unsure what I'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not be adding items to the map while other threads are using it. You need to prevent that situation.

Comment: Questions like this require a [mcve], in particular to answer what kind of synchronization you have.

Comment: None of the C++ library containers are thread safe. Even if the keys are different, when updating maps, maps are not thread safe, and this is undefined behavior. End of story.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm unsure what kind of synchronization I have or what that means. I can try creating a minimal reproducible example if that helps, but in terms of what I'm doing here, I've just created six threads running a function that runs cfr once, and right after creating the threads, I join all six threads.

Comment: You may need a `std::mutex` [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)

Comment: If you don't know what synchronization means in the context of multithreaded programming, you should keep on reading a tutorial on that topic, because that is a very basic concept.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see, ok, thanks. I'll look into ways to ensure that the threads are updating separate maps.

Comment: You have a data race on `nodeMap`, because multiple threads modify the map concurrently (`insert`). This results in undefined behavior.

You have to synchronize access to the map, e.g. using a mutex. It is safe for multiple threads to _read_ the map (e.g., find/iterate), as long as it is guaranteed that no thread _modifies_ the map while others are reading it. But in this case you would have to ensure a happens-before relation between the reading threads and any potential update that should be visible to the read operation.

Comment: Threads all execute in the same address space of the process. So they have to take care not to step on eachothers toes. That's where synchronization comes in. Even seemingly simple things like writing to a variable is *not* inherently safe in a multithreaded program. Threads are *hard* / *difficult*.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: All C++ containers are thread safe. You can call any function from multiple threads, even in a reentrant way. That is not the problem. The problem is writing to the same object from multiple threads without synchronization. This object can be any object not specifically designed to support that use, so not just containers, but also a simple `bool`. One such object designed to be used by multiple threads is `std::mutex`, to give a counter example as well.

Comment: No, @UlrichEckhardt, none of the containers are thread-safe, and nowhere close to being reentrant. You are mistaken.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container, see the box about thread safety. While this is far from normative, consider it nonetheless. Also, please think about what different meanings "thread safe" can take! In and of itself, the term is pretty meaningless, unless it serves as a placeholder for more concrete guarantees. You see those guarantees in that box. Anything not there must be considered in the realm of either implementation-defined behaviour or undefined behaviour. I think you meant something different, which is why I called you out to define it.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - check it out yourself, specifically "on different containers" part, which is in the very first sentence. The only thing that different threads can safely call on the ***same*** container are `const` functions (2nd paragraph). But in the context of ***modifying*** containers, which is the question here, none of the containers are thread safe, for modification. Furthermore, all the parts referencing "elements of the container" are discussing the ***values*** in the container, and not the container itself. You are still mistaken.

Comment: "The problem is writing to the same object from multiple threads without synchronization." -- I'm well aware of how things work. Maybe you should take the time and read what people write? Also, quoting you: "None of the C++ library containers are thread safe." which -as it stands- is simply wrong, according to the definition of thread safety used by the relevant standards. Moreover, it's not really helpful, since it's a broad over-generalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone in the comments for helping me understand where I was wrong.

I created the following minimal reproducible example to test the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>

const int NUM_THREADS = 6;

void test(std::unordered_map<int, int>& map, int thread) {
    for(int i = thread; i < 1000; i += NUM_THREADS) {
        if (map.find(i) == map.end())
            map.insert(std::make_pair(i, i * i));
        if (map.find(i) == map.end())
            std::cout << "Preposterous" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map;

    std::thread threads[NUM_THREADS];
    for(int core = 0; core < NUM_THREADS; core++){
        threads[core] = std::thread(test, std::ref(map), core);
    }
    for(auto & thread : threads){
        thread.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here 6 threads are running `test` passing a reference to a map and a thread number. Each thread is writing to independent keys in map (thread 0 writes to i = 0, 6, 12, ...; thread 1 writes to i = 1, 7, 13, ...; and so on). Despite this, the code still leads to undefined behavior, and "Preposterous" is occasionally printed.

The issue is as @SamVarshavchik explained. C++ library containers are not thread safe. Even if the keys are different, when updating maps, maps are not thread safe, and trying to update them on multiple threads leads to undefined behavior.

For my context, since the keys are independent, I'm considering creating maps for each set of independent keys, and then only passing the map that will be changed to a thread when it needs to be changed. As a result, no thread will ever be changing the same map.

Thanks for all the help!